# Почему в обобщённом методе не работает компаратор?

Tags: java, generics, compare

**Само задание:**

Определен `enum CompareResult {LESS, EQUAL, GREATER};`

Создайте статический метод с именем compare, который содержит 2 параметра обобщающего типа, и сравнивает их через метод `compareTo()`. Метод compare должен возвращать `CompareResult`, причем

```
CompareResult.LESS если первый параметр меньше второго
CompareResult.GREATER если первый параметр больше второго
CompareResult.EQUAL если первый параметр равен второму
```

**Мой код:**

```
public static <T> CompareResult compare(T one, T two) {
        int s = one.compareTo(two);//эта стока кода не работает
        if (s > 0) return CompareResult.GREATER;
        if (s < 0) return CompareResult.LESS;
        return CompareResult.EQUAL;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо, чтобы объекты были `Comparable`, чтобы можно было вызывать метод `compareTo()`.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> CompareResult compare(T one, T two) {
        int s = one.compareTo(two);
        if (s > 0) return CompareResult.GREATER;
        if (s < 0) return CompareResult.LESS;
        return CompareResult.EQUAL;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.