# Распознавание типов в компараторе Java

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение, comparator

Пусть есть некий класс `Test`, содержащий поле `field` типа `int`:

```
class Test {
    private final int field;

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public Test(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(field);
    }
}
```

Есть список `List<Test> list` объектов класса `Test`, который мы хотим отсортировать посредством компаратора по полю `field`.

Компаратор для такой сортировки может выглядеть так:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(test -> test.getField()));
```

Понятно, что тут можно сократить до "method reference", но об этом речь позже.

Метод `comparingInt()` ожидает на вход тип `ToIntFunction<? super T>`, где `T` в нашем случае является классом `Test`. Очевидно, что в этой лямбде тип `test` распознаётся как  `Test`, мы спокойно вызываем его метод `getField()` и получаем корректную лямбду.

Но если написать вот так:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(test -> test.getField()).reversed());
```

то компилятор будет ругаться, говоря, что `test` имеет тип `Object`, в котором, разумеется, метода `getField()` нет.

Убрать эту ошибку можно тремя разными способами:

- заместо лямбды сделать "method reference"
- оставить лямбду, но привести её к типу `ToIntFunction<Test>`
- оставить лямбду, но явно указать в ней тип переменной `test` как `Test`

Не считая, конечно, того варианта, когда мы создаём свой отдельный класс, реализующий `Comparator<Test>`.

---

Собственно, **вопрос**: почему вообще возникает такая ошибка? Из-за чего получается так, что при последующем вызове метода `reversed()` Java отказывается распознавать тип `test` как `Test`?
Причём такой же эффект возникает, если к создаваемому компаратору пытаться применять, например, метод `thenComparing()`.

Comment: Для того, чтобы отсортировать коллекцию нужно писать компаратор, а объекту надо дать `Comparable`, чтобы его можно было сравнивать. См. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1285386/204920).

Comment: `list.sort(Comparator.<Test>comparingInt(test -> test.getField()).reversed());`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy и правда, о таком варианте записи я как-то позабыл. Спасибо. Но меня удивляет другое: почему в одном случае нам не надо явно писать тип (хотя, конечно, никто не мешает), а в другом - надо обязательно его как-то указать. В том числе, и тем способом, который вы привели.

Comment: Я сейчас выясняю этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821670/13279831): [Why does type inference fail for lambda, but succeed for equivalent method reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814110/):

**Почему извлечение типа не работает для лямбды, но успешно отрабатывает для эквивалентной ссылки на метод?**

Из спецификации языка [JLS §15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> В отличие от лямбда-выражения, ссылка на метод может быть конгруэнтной (соответствующей) типу обобщенной функции (то есть функции, имеющей параметры типа).  Это связано с тем, что лямбда-выражение должно иметь возможность объявлять параметры типа, и ни один синтаксис это не поддерживает; в то же время для ссылки на метод такое объявление типа не требуется.

Лямбда выражение вызывает ошибку компиляции поскольку не указан *явно* аргумент типа...

Что касается ссылок на метод, то поскольку тип может быть извлечён из параметров метода, явный аргумент типа не нужен, как указано выше в спецификации языка.

---

Это известное ограничение в механизме извлечения типа, который недостаточно "силён", чтобы сделать сразу два шага.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(test -> test.getField())); // OK
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(test -> test.getField()).reversed()); // FAIL
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getField).reversed()); // ОК
```

Чтобы извлечь тип `test` в лямбде, должен быть определён целевой тип лямбды.
В первом случае это просто, так как метод `list.sort` ожидает в качестве параметра `Comparator<Test>`, который успешно возвращается статическим методом `Comparator.comparingInt`:  `Comparator<Test> comparingInt(t -> t.getField())`.  В свою очередь, `comparingInt` ожидает функцию, преобразующую тип `Test` в `int`, то есть переменная `test` в лямбде *должна* иметь тип `Test`.

При вызове обобщённого метода `reversed()` после лямбды с неявной типизацией этот механизм "ломается", так как в этом контексте недостаточно информации для определения целевого типа лямбды.  Здесь результат `comparingInt` передаётся дальше по цепочке в `reversed()`, который также возвращает некий тип `Comparator<T>` для *текущего экземпляра компаратора*, но целевой тип `Test` в данном случае не может быть передан назад из `reversed`.  Поэтому в случае сомнений компилятор решает, что целевым типом является `Object` и возникает указанная ошибка.

При использовании же ссылки на метод информация о целевом типе присутствует явно, то есть, нет необходимости в дополнительном извлечении типа, и `reversed()` и принимает и отдает `Comparator<Test>`.

Соответственно, другие варианты записи, которые позволяют однозначно определить целевой тип, будут успешно компилироваться:

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Test test) -> test.getField()).reversed()); // ОК
list.sort(Comparator.<Test>comparingInt(test -> test.getField()).reversed()); // ОК
list.sort(Comparator.<Test,Integer>comparing(test -> test.getField()).reversed()); // ОК
```

Эта проблема была обнаружена достаточно давно и обсуждается достаточно часто, см.:

- [`Comparator.reversed()` does not compile using lambda (Aug 7, 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/)
- [Very confused by Java 8 Comparator type inference (Jun 26, 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/)
- [When does Java require explicit type parameters? (Jul 12, 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370113/)
  и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылки! Я пытался найти информацию на английском, но гуглил другое, что-то вроде "Когда может понадобиться явное указание типа в компараторе", поэтому приведённых вами вопросов не нашёл) Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: "но целевой тип Test в данном случае не может быть передан назад из reversed" -  почему? Тип значения возвращаемого из `reversed` совпадает с типом `this`. Информации достаточно.

Comment: Вывод типа достаточно силен что обработать любую цепочку вызовов методов. Только обработка `this` проваливается.